# How to custom the binding of WebService(Not WCF) in WebForm

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I created a web service in Asp.net.(Not WCF)But how can I custom the binding of it? It will automatically generate two type of binding(soap & soap12).
I only want one of them.How Can I custom the binding type?

Answer (score 0):

ASMX web services don't have the concept of a binding.